# Emacs using Ido no longer remembers buffer list between sessions

Tags: emacs, ido

When i `C-x b` to get the list of buffers (using ido) on my Linux installation of Emacs 24.3 i have a list of the recent buffers in grey. When i open a few buffers and the `C-x b` again these are now listed in white. So there appears to be two groups of buffers in the buffer list - 'opened this session' and 'opened previously'.

I recently installed Emacs 24.3 on Windows and this behaviour does not appear. I only have a 'opened this session' list of buffers when i `C-x b`. How can i add the 'opened previously' list?

Comment: Perhaps the variable `ido-save-directory-list-file` would be helpful?

Comment: the above variable does not cause this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable `ido-use-virtual-buffers` causes recently opened files to be listed in the `C-x b` list.

```
(setq ido-use-virtual-buffers t)
```

this variable is set in the package `starter-kit`.